# twilio.AccessToken is "not a constructor" in TypeScript on Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, twilio

I tried this with TypeScript on Firebase Functions:

```
import * as twilio from 'twilio';
function generateToken(iden,room){
    const token = new twilio.AccessToken(
        envconf.twilio.sid,
        envconf.twilio.apikey,
        envconf.twilio.apisecret,
    )
    token.identity = iden;
    const grant = new twilio.AccessToken.VideoGrant()
    token.addGrant(grant);
   return token.toJwt();
}
```

but I get this error in logs:

```
TypeError: AccessToken is not a constructor
```

but this is like how they did it in the [documentations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/identity). So maybe I should switch from TypeScript to Javascript?

### UPDATE:

I moved it to the Javascript, I get the same error. So this is not a TypeScript/Javascript compatibility issue.

### UPDATE 2:

I changed

`const token = new twilio.AccessToken(`

to

```
const token = new twilio.jwt.AccessToken(
```

and for some reason, it worked!
I didn't post this update as an answer, because I don't understand why what they wrote in the example doesn't work and this works!

Comment: I believe that you have found a mistake in our documentation. I'm going to get that fixed as soon as I can. Hope your app is continuing as planned now.

Comment: Yes, the app is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake in the documentation, and they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import twilio as :

```
const { twilio} = require('twilio');
```

Or

```
import { twilio } from 'twilio'
```